# MySQL 5.6 missing ndbcluster engine?

Tags: mysql

When trying to do a `rails` migration (creating a table) in Mysql it gives me the error:

> Mysql::Error: Unknown storage engine 'ndbcluster'

It was working fine until I installed mysql 5.6

When I run `show engines`, `ndb` is not found

What Can I do to add this engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install ndbcluster version instead of normal mysql5.5, Plesae check below-

> The NDB storage engine is not supported in standard MySQL 5.6
>   releases. Currently supported MySQL Cluster releases include MySQL
>   Cluster NDB 7.1, which is based on MySQL 5.1; MySQL Cluster NDB 7.2,
>   which is based on MySQL 5.5; and MySQL Cluster NDB 7.3, which is based
>   on MySQL 5.6. While based on MySQL Server, these releases also contain
>   support for NDB. MySQL Cluster NDB 7.4, currently in development and
>   also based on MySQL 5.6, is now also available in a Developer
>   Milestone release.

You can check details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engines.html)